# How to RemoveAll when using generic list<T> in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

If I use generic list like this:

```
$foo = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.list[object]'
$foo.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name="Foo1"; }))
$foo.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name="Foo2"; }))
$foo.Add((New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name="foo3"; }))
```

How can I apply RemoveAll() method of `List<T>`? Is it possible to use predicates? How can I for example remove all items that start with capital 'F'?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the only way is without using `System.Predicate` that needs delegates (sorry, but  really I can't figure out how create anonymous delegates in powershell) and use the where-object clause.

In my example I re-assign the result to same `$foo` variable that need to be cast again to `list<T>`.

To avoid error if result count is only one it need the ',' to create always an `array` value

```
[system.collections.generic.list[object]]$foo =  , ( $foo | ? {$_.name  -cnotmatch "^f" })
```

**EDIT:**

After some test I've found how use lambda expression using powershell scriptblock:

```
$foo.removeAll( { param($m)  $m.name.startswith( 'F', $false , $null)  })
```

This is the right way for using method that needs `System.Predicate` in powershell

Comment: hell that looks ugly. Well if it works who cares, right? Thank you!

Comment: I bet one could invoke the DLR within Powershell and construct an anonymous method that could be passed as a lambda. I'm certainly not going to try to write that, myself, though :).

Comment: @Shibumi I've found how pass lambda without invoke DLR. Read my edit.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another option using scriptblocks (anonymous delegates):

```
$foo.RemoveAll( {$args[0].Name -clike 'F*'} )
```

Answer (score -1):

It turns out I really wanted the .clear() method rather than RemoveAll.  RemoveAll is only required if you want to remove a group of items rather than all items in the list.